# Find XAML Framework Elements Bounded To An Object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How can I find and access to Elements which are bind to an object in XAML ?

**Edit :** Let's say I have a `EmployeeViewModel` which is assigned to `EmployeeView`'s `DataContext` and a `EmployeeModel` inside my `EmployeeViewModel`, I want to know which properties of my model bounded to View's Framework Elements (Controls) also I want to have an access to each control bounded to my model properties.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Provide a sample of object that you want to find.

Comment: do you want the controls at ViewModel or at View?

Comment: you want to do it from inside your application code, or using third-party tools? or intending to build a custom one?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code? MVVM is meant to keep your UI logic and your application logic totally separate, so your `EmployeeViewModel` and your `EmployeeModel` should never reference UI components such as `Buttons` or `TextBoxes`

Comment: @Rachel I know how should I implement MVVM, It was a example of what I try to do, Maybe I couldn't make my self clear about my problem. I'm trying to create a small validation framework for WPF and a control like ValidationSummary in Silverlight. I just want to know how can I find and access controls bindings and controls inside View. So I can change their style based on validation result.

Comment: @SaberAmani Typically validation in WPF is done with the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) interface. You can adjust which validation template to use with the [Validation.ErrorTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx) attached property, or adjust the `Style` of your XAML objects based on the `Validation.HasError` property. I'd highly recommend going that route instead of having your Models and ViewModels work with UI objects

Comment: I fully agree with Rachel : what you're doing is fighting the framework instead of working with it. Use standard Validation in WPF, you'll meet your goal in far less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: In light of the question being clarified by SaberAmani in that he is trying to add validation to his models and show a validation summary..see the links below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/wpf-validation-summary-control/

http://wpfvalidation.codeplex.com/

http://f10andf11.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/wpf-validation-summary-control.html

---

For reference for people that want to discover Bindings:

You don't mention if your XAML is in WPF, Silverlight, Metro or Phone7 (thus you may be more restricted in what you can do).

There seem to be a few possible ways to do what you want:

1. Reflection
2. MarkupObject / MarkupWriter
3. TypeDescriptor+DependencyPropertyDescriptor
4. Custom Binding Markup Extension

Take a look at this link.

- http://blog.spencen.com/2008/05/02/how-to-get-a-list-of-bindings-in-wpf.aspx

He uses reflection and suggests this is the classical way to do it...but also mentions MarkupWriter as another possibility. NOTE: the reflection method doesn't discover Attached Properties which may have bindings.

Here are some links that use MarkupWriter...this would allow you to discover the attached properties.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21139/An-XAML-Serializer-Preserving-Bindings
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marlat/archive/2009/05/24/getbindingexpression-a-good-way-to-iterate-over-all-dependency-properties-in-visual-tree-in-silverlight-3.aspx

Related links:

- [Retrieve all Data Bindings from WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586870/retrieve-all-data-bindings-from-wpf-window)
- Getting list of all dependency/attached properties of an Object 
  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/580234cb-e870-4af1-9a91-3e3ba118c89c

Answer (score 2):

you could use reflection to loop through properties and use FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression on each property to build, for a given Framework element, all its bindings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression

Comment: Once you have the BindingExpression, the DataItem gives you the source for the Binding. Please tell more about what you're trying to achieve if you want some more help.