# Get a list of all bound properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What would be the most efficient way to get a list of all data bound properties in the ViewModel. I have a Window that has one ViewModel and multiple user controls that are show depending on user selection. I use IDataErrorInfo for my validations. I want to know which properties are bound to so that only those can be validated when the user clicks the save button.

Below is my current implementation and i am concerned some properties might end up in the list and get validated by mistake.

```
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private bool _validate = false;

    private List<string> _boundProperties = new List<string>();

    private void OnPropertyBound(string propertyName)
    {
    }

    public string Property1
    {
        get { OnPropertyBound("Property1"); return "value1"; }
    }

    public string Property2
    {
        get { OnPropertyBound("Property2"); return "value2"; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_boundProperties.Contains(columnName)) return null;
            if (!_validate) return null; // Set to true when user tries to save. OnPropertyChanged event also fired to refresh the bindings afterwards.

            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Property1":
                    // Some validation code that sets the errorMessage
                    break;
                case "Property2":
                    // Some validation code that sets the errorMessage
                    break;
            }

            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should use this case in your ViewModel, but [VisualTreeHelper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586870/retrieve-all-data-bindings-from-wpf-window) can helps you. Duplicate?

Comment: This question should help you in what you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586870/retrieve-all-data-bindings-from-wpf-window

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  The suggestions given above will cost you more time and effort than simply validating everything.  Don't waste your time on it.

Comment: I don't even see how there would be a practical way of achieving this. Assuming your view model uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`, there's not even a per-property relationship between the model and bound targets. You'd have to inspect the event handler, and even then a handler could be written in such a way that static analysis won't give you the information you need. Without a good [mcve] it's hard to be sure, but it sounds like you may be abusing the property binding system and setting yourself up for a lot of hard-to-find, hard-to-fix bugs later down the road.